# Weird customization behaviour for e-mail entity in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We are using Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise.
We want to send an e-mail from a workflow. 
We got a lot of experience creating workflows, so this is probably not a newbie question.

We have a weird behaviour when we try to send an e-mail. 
We tried the "Send E-Mail task" and also "Create entity record" of type "E-Mail". Both show the same behaviour.

I am attaching two screenshots. In that example we are attaching the workflow to a custom entity "Anlagenteil" but the error is the same for all entities we tried. When we try to configure the e-mail, it is not possible to set any values. So, on the second screenshot, the list below "Anlagenteil" is always empty. 
This is also true when we try to set the value of the subject/topic which is just text. 
(We know that we can't add text to the To/CC fields)

The same workflows works just fine when we try "phonecall" or some other activity entity. 
The misbehaviour is the same for all users and on different computers.

There seems to be something broken with the e-mail entity in our environment and we have no idea where we could start looking for a fix. Any ideas?

[image: Workflow]

[image: E-Mail-Entity]

Update: We found out that this is a rendering issue. It doesn't work in Firefox or Edge but it does work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I would go with the following strategy to troubleshoot this issue: create some clean Organization on the same instance of CRM. Create the same workflow (not on cutom entity, but on out-of-the-box entity, as you said it should also be broken). If everything is fine (it should be otherwise you do not have broken email - you have broken CRM installation) then import email from your "broken" org to your vanilla org. Check if it has "broken" the email. If yes, then you are sure it's somewhere within email metadata. Now export vanilla email and your broken email in a solution and compare them.

Comment: Try IE compatibility mode

Comment: Yes, IE in compat mode works. This gets us back to work but still this can't be the long-term solution that some (or one) entities can only be used in workflow when running IE in compat mode.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried creating a new Form for the Email entity and using that one in the Workflow Designer? We've experienced problems like this in the past due to Form Customizations and it was solved by using another form.

Keep in mind that the Workflow Designer uses the Sticky Forms, so in order to change the form used in the Workflow Designer, just switch forms in the UI.

Comment: Excellent idea. We tried it but it didn't help. But you are right that it is some kind of rendering issue: We found out that it works with Internet Explorer but not with Firefox.